# Select dynamic checkbox uipath selector

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I want to checkbox row in a table.
The row number is stored in a variable rowNum.
In selector, it shows
`<webctrl id='tblResult_0' tag='INPUT' type='checkbox' />`
This selects row 0. I want to select what is stored in rowNum.
How do I do that in UiPath?
Its a click activity.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on which system you use.

So to go with your example: `<webctrl id='tblResult_0' tag='INPUT' type='checkbox' />`

### Without Object repository

- First add an `Assign` activity before you use the dynamic selector
- Now set the dynamic selector to a new variable `num` in the `Assign` activity

  - Set `num` to `0`
- Use that new variable `num` now as selector input wherever you want like so

  - `"<webctrl id='tblResult_" + num + "' tag='INPUT' type='checkbox' />"`

### With Object repository

With OR it's much easier. Here, we don't need an `Assign` activity anymore.

- First, create a variable without the `Assign` activity
- Now set the dynamic selector to a new variable `num` in the `Variables` tab

  - Set `num` to `0`
- Use that new variable `num` now as selector input in your Object repository selector
- `"<webctrl id='tblResult_{{num}}' tag='INPUT' type='checkbox' />"`
- Here an example screenshot of one of my own processes:
- [image]

Comment: You have a minor typo: `"<webctrl id='tblResult_'" + num + "tag='INPUT' type='checkbox' />"` should be `"<webctrl id='tblResult_'" + num + "' tag='INPUT' type='checkbox' />"`

Comment: Indeed, but you also had a typo :) Hard with all the commas in pseudo coding.